# Using java to run multiple commands in terminal?

Tags: java, command, line

Is there a way to write and run `.bat` files in Java then delete them after, or doing so in java without the use of batch files, I need each client to be loaded on its own instance of prompt.

Here's my loader class

```
public class TBotLoader implements Runnable {

    private Thread t;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private int script;
    private String acc;
    private String proxy;
    private int world;

    public TBotLoader(String name, String password, int script, String acc, String proxy, int world){
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.script = script;
        this.acc = acc;
        this.proxy = proxy;
        this.world = world;
        System.out.println("Creating Thread: " + acc);
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar " + home + "/Documents/proj/jar.jar" + " -s " + this.script + " -a " + this.acc + " -n " + this.name + " -pw " + this.password + " -w " + this.world + " -proxy " + this.proxy);
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to spawn clients");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Starting thread: " + this.acc);
        t = new Thread(this, acc);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're talking about terminal (unix) but also about bat files (Windows), what OS are you targeting?

Comment: Windows, misuse of the word "terminal". Please replace with "prompt".

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose the problem here. Please provide a MVCE. As for the .bat writing, I highly doubt Java provides support for writing batch files, as they are platform specific.

Comment: `.bat` files can just be text files with that extension, so Java can handle those.

Comment: Java can write .bat files since they are just text files with a bat extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `.bat` files are just text files, you can use a `FileOutputStream` to create them. I would then look into `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("");` or `ProcessBuilder` to execute them and then just delete the file when done.

**See Also**

[Runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)

[ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Comment: Thanks for being able to understand my problem! Got everything working fine! Once again thanks!